# Showing AUTOINCREMENT Id with @GeneratedValue to final user

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to persist an entity with JPA in a Spring Boot project.
I had an interface repository which implements JpaRepository, like this:

```
@Repository
public interface SonClass extends FatherClass<SonClass> {
    //some especific methods
}
```

That interface extends this one by inheritance:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface FatherClass<T extends FatherClass> extends CrudRepository<T, Integer>{

}
```

This is the entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "father_table")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "pk_father_column")
public class SonClassEntity extends FatherClassEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "numero", nullable = false)
    private Integer numero;
```

I'm trying to make the field/column "numero" Autoincrement, and then show the generated value to the final user.
The problem happens when I persist the entity, and inmediately afther that, show the generated value:

```
sonClassRepository.save(sonClassEntity);
return Optional.of(cuponDigitalEntidad).map(cuponDTOMapper).orElseThrow();
```

In the database, the values are Ok. The problem is in memory.
What could be the issue here?

Thanks!

The generated value is null.
I want the value.

Answer (score 0):

The `save` call should return you the stored version of your entity. You need to re-assign it:

```java
sonClassEntity = sonClassRepository.save(sonClassEntity);
```

After that the field should be filled with the generated value.

Comment: It didn't worked.
I'm using @Transactional in the Service class that calls the repository. This could be the problem?

Comment: Try to use `saveAndFlush` instead of `save`

Comment: It didn't work either. The only solution for the moment, is a specific method with @Query, take the value, and setting it manually to the entity. I personally don't like this solution, so i'll keep trying to achieve this problem with other solutions.